# db2: how to connect to favorite/prefer db?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

On Oracle is easy

```
sqlplus myuser/mypass@remotehost/nameofdborcontainer
```

On db2 I do this

```
db2
connect to mydb
```

How to connect automatically to mydb?

Comment: Do you mean on the command line? No, you need to execute the CONNECT command or script it. What is a "default" database?

Comment: Default database is the db I usually connect, but probably best term is favorite/prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot always draw parallels between Oracle and Db2, because these DBMSes have very different architecture.

Historically an Oracle instance was only able to support one database, so connecting to an instance and the database were essentially the same thing. Recently this has changed with the introduction of pluggable databases, but the SQL*Plus behaviour remained backwards-compatible.

Db2 for LUW has always supported multiple databases per instances, so a `connect` command has been necessary to choose one of them.

You can avoid having to explicitly connect to a database by setting the [registry variable `DB2DBDFT`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.regvars.doc/doc/r0005657.html) that specifies the default database name for implicit connections. If it is set, any SQL statement will cause the client to connect to the specified database automatically.